# Equivalence between CH and existence of certain sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: set-theory

The problem is to prove the following equivalence:

$$2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1 \iff \exists\ A,B\in\mathbb{R}^2:\\ \textrm{a)}A\cup B=\mathbb{R}^2
\\\textrm{b)}\ \forall\ \textrm{lines } l\ \textrm{parallel to x-axis, } |A\cap l|\leq\aleph_0
\\\textrm{c)}\ \forall\ \textrm{lines } l\ \textrm{parallel to y-axis, } |B\cap l|\leq\aleph_0$$

I think I know how to prove "$\impliedby$":

Let's assume the RHS and that $2^{\aleph_0}\geq\aleph_2$. Now let's take a sequence $\langle x_{\alpha}:\ \alpha<\omega_1\rangle$. Since $\bigcup_\limits{\alpha<\omega_1}|B\cap x_{\alpha}|\leq \aleph_1\cdot\aleph_0=\aleph_1$ there is such a $y$-coordinate that neither of $(x_{\alpha},y)$ is in $B$. But hence we obtain $\aleph_1$ point which all lie on the same line parallel to $x$-axis. Since $A\cup B=\mathbb{R}^2$ they all must be contained in $A$ $-$ a contradiction as $A$ has at most countably many of those points.

But what about the other implication? Do I contruct these sets by induction? Over all lines or something else? I haven't come up with anything yet, perhaps you could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Let $\sqsubseteq$ well-order $\mathbb R$ of order type $\omega_1$. Being a relation, $\sqsubseteq$ is a subset of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$. Perhaps that will work as either $A$ or $B$?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I need to think about it a moment :D

Comment: I still don't get it :( Maybe a hint to a hint? I mean: Every linear order contains a cofinal well-order. So what if $\sqsubseteq$ is a cofinal well order on some line $l$ with natural order?

Comment: @Jules: You're overcomplicating it :). Assuming CH, there is a bijection $\varphi:\mathbb R\to\omega_1$. Then define $x\sqsubseteq y$ iff $\varphi(x)\le\varphi(y)$. This gives you a well-ordering of _all of_ $\mathbb R$ of order type $\omega_1$. In particular $\{x\in\mathbb R\mid x\sqsubseteq a\}$ is at most countable for every $a$.

Comment: @Jules: Remember what an ordering _is_. An ordering such as $\sqsubseteq$ is a particular case of a _relation_, which is, in and of itself, a set of pairs, that is, a subset of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$. The set $\sqsubseteq$ _itself_ can be your $A$. And then $B$ becomes $\mathbb R^2 \setminus {\sqsubseteq}$.

Comment: But don't I need a set on which I impose this order? A set of elements that this relation pertains to? I guess it should be $\mathbb{R}^2$ here.

Comment: @Jules: $\sqsubseteq$ is a relation on $\mathbb R$. That means $\sqsubseteq$ is _itself_ a subset of $\mathbb R^2$: $$ {\sqsubseteq} = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 \mid x\sqsubseteq y \} $$

Comment: Yes, yes, you're right. Ok, I think I got it now :))) A set of pairs, ooooh! Cool, a great thanks!